# Change the parser.add argument value automatically

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

I have a python script that accepts two arguments one is the audio file path and the other is the model path. This script is used to denoise the audio files.

I have multiple audio files. How can I change the path of the audio files automatically in the `--file_name` argument for example after running this file do the second file

```sh
python test_audio.py --file_name p232_160.wav --epoch_name generator-80.pkl
python test_audio.py --file_name p232_161.wav --epoch_name generator-80.pkl
python test_audio.py --file_name p232_162.wav --epoch_name generator-80.pkl
```

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I am using Linux

Answer (score 0):

You have two options

1. Use a shell script to change the value *before* you call python. Here's an example bash script.

```sh
files=($(ls p232_*.wav))

for file in ${files[@]}
do
    python test_audio.py --file_name $file --epoch_name generator-80.pkl
done
```

2. Modify your python script to accept a pattern and use `glob` to retrieve files that match the pattern ([documentation here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html))

```py
import glob

pattern = args.file_name
filenames = glob.glob(pattern)

for file_name in filenames:
    # process each file
```

and then call this script like:

```sh
python test_audio.py --file_name p232_*.wav --epoch_name generator-80.pk1
```